# IPTables won't open the port on my Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ubuntu, server, iptables

Just recently bought a VPS (2core, 100tb ssd, 4gb ram) and I'm trying to run a Teamspeak 3 server on it. The server is up and running but I can't seem to open the necessary ports. I'm really inexperienced with Ubuntu so I tried to configure the IPTables through information I found here. For some reason though the ports are not open.

I'll dump my iptables log below.

Hope you can help.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9987
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:30033
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:search
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2008
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10011
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:9987
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:30033
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:2010
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:2008
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:10011

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:9987
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9987
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:9987
```

Comment: Settings firewall if you got one and IPTABLES config for teamspeak3 : https://www.vultr.com/docs/setting-up-teamspeak-3-on-debian-wheezy

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I added the tables from the given page. Yet the port doesn't seem to be open yet. https://gyazo.com/0d97ab3ddbe6cd977321ae8c861dd6fa

Weird aswell is that I'm on SSH, yet I don't see the SSH port in these iptables. Could it be that the portforwarding is managed externally?

Comment: you can add the expression on IPTABLE to route SSH port : ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:SSHPORT

Comment: Apparently the port is open already, that's what I mean. I'm connected to the SSH, but the port is not visible in the tables.

Comment: If you use a VPS it can be cosed by the rescue system you got and the ssh server is setting on there i guess .

Comment: Just mailed my host who said the VPS is unmanaged. However my iptables are now empty and some ports (i.e. 10011) are still open. The hoster told me that I should be able to configure them through ssh but for some reason iptables don't affect the ports.

Comment: And I can see that some ports are open in netstat, yet there are no ports in the iptables

Comment: Did you use a hosting server as OVH | 1&1  ... or use your own ?

Comment: It's working now :) Thanks for your input, found the solution on that teamspeak url you posted

Comment: Welcome gl for the next ;).